# CSS Div appearing and disappearing Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple CSS animation so that when a person clicks a button it will display a simple message (like steam when a players started something)

I'm trying to learn CSS, whar I did was this:

```
@keyframes item-adcionado {
    0% {
        z-index: -100;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        z-index: 200;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -100;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes item-adcionado {
    0% {
        z-index: -100;
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        z-index: 200;
        opacity: 1;
        bottom: 5%;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -100;
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 0%;
    }
}
.item-nao-adicionado {
    z-index: -100;
    width: 10%;
    height: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #696969;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}
.item-adc {
    z-index: -100;
    width: 10%;
    height: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #696969;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    animation: item-adcionado 10s ease;
    -webkit-animation: item-adcionado 10s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The div:

```
<div class="item-nao-adicionado" id="item-nao-adicionado"><h2>Jogo adicionado ao carrinho</h2></div>
```

The Change code:

```
document.getElementById("item-nao-adicionado").className = "item-adc";
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @Rohit like steam, when appears that the players is playing something, It's just to avois to use alerts on the site